# How can I change axis in my plot?

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

I have surface plotted with code I copied from sourceforge.net. I want to change the axes labelling from the one given, which does not render correctly when incorporated in a tex document anywat. I want my axes to depict the fact that all the points are below x=0. Similarly if I plot

```
\addplot3[surf] {-x^2 - y^2}
```

I want it to show all points are above z=0. My consulting pgfmanual.pdf has not been helpful so far. I also want to be able to scale the plot (increase or decrease its size).

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, decorations.pathreplacing, matrix}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}

\addplot3[surf] {-x^2 - y^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You need to check the manual of `pgfplots` package not PGF

Comment: @ZiloreMumba, have you found out in the meantime how to achieve the desired output by having a look in the `pgfplots`' manual?

Comment: the pgfmanual.pdf and pgfplots.pdf are so difficult to use. Unless you already know ho to do something, you do not get anything from them. Example I have "\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{120}" in one of my plotting codes. A search for "\tdplotsetmaincoords" in either of the manuals yields nothing.

Comment: My suggestion is, that you don't _read_ the manuals, but just have a look at the pictures first and if you see some similar pictures as the one you want to draw, then have a look at the corresponding code and adapt it to your needs. Regarding the `\tdplotsetmaincoords` command: Googling it, I found that this belongs to the [`tikz-3dplot` package](http://www.bakoma-tex.com/doc/latex/tikz-3dplot/tikz-3dplot_documentation.pdf#page=15).

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, as a matter of fact, I do have geogebra installed, so I realised if I draw in geogebra and generate tikz code, I am able to have the graphic I want as well as learn the code.

Comment: Do note that Geogebra sometimes produces rubbish code (at least last time I looked, which admittedly is a while back).

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you have found the solution yourself in meanwhile. If not ...

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            % change the width of the plot
            width=7cm,
            % change the `zmin' value
            % (0 makes no sense here, because that is the maximum value
            %  of the given function. That is why I have chosen -10 here.)
            zmin=-10,
        ]
            \addplot3 [surf] {-x^2 - y^2};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]